# How to use Retrofit in an android app to communicate with a laravel web page

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit

I have developed a web page using laravel. Now I’m making an android app but I need to get data from that web page. I have done some research and found retrofit to achieve that but I’m not sure about how it would be. I’d appreciate any response with code, explanations or resources that may help.
Thank you.

Comment: Has an API been created on your web page with the laravel infrastructure you have created?

Comment: @alihanc what do you mean?

Comment: You need the API to be able to send data through the web page you created with Laravel. Did you create an API? I'm asking to be sure, so I will share the relevant resources accordingly.

Comment: I haven’t created an API. I just made the web page with the database, relations, models and routes and it works. I have the information stored in the database but I don’t know how to make an api. And thank you for answering @alihanc

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the necessary data for the current mobile application via API.

I leave the stages and resources in order.

**What is API?**
Source 1: https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/api/ 
Source 2: https://www.guru99.com/what-is-api.html
Source 3: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByGJQzlzxQg

**What is REST API?**
Source 1: https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/restful-api/
Source 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mN3VyJuCjM

**How to create API with Laravel?**
Source 1: https://juangsalazprabowo.medium.com/creating-restful-api-using-laravel-e68ee61fa583
Source 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGqCZjdgJJk
*Additional Laravel API documentation:* https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources

*Finally, this might come in handy:* https://www.cloudways.com/blog/connect-android-app-with-laravel-api/

By following the steps above, you can connect to the **API** using **Retrofit** and access the relevant data. Good luck.